# Blazor Unmarshalled JavaScript interop

Tags: blazor-webassembly, javascript-interop

To improve performance in Blazor JS Interop calls, synchronous and unmarshalled apis are available

I struggle to find more information regarding the unmarshalled.

For example:

```
//javascript
JSFunctions.f1 = function (fields) {
    var f1 = Blazor.platform.readStringField(fields, 0);
    var f2 = Blazor.platform.readStringField(fields, 4);
    var f3 = Blazor.platform.readStringField(fields, 8);
};


//F#
[<Inject>]
member val Js: IJSRuntime
let js = this.Js :?> IJSUnmarshalledRuntime
js.InvokeUnmarshalled<ElementReference, string, unit>("JSFunctions.f1", er, txt)
```

1. Where are the functions Blazor.platform.* defined?
2. Which one should be used to retrieve an argument of type ElementReference?
3. What is the second int parameter of the function readStringField and how should it be used?

Comment: Regarding to question 2, I think you better use marshaled version since by the way you should do same in js to work with it. I find out that ElementReference is a struct which only have one useful field: Id (which can get as string in field offset 0 in unmarshalled way) and also context. Then you should use _bl_+Id to reterive element Id of html element in js and use document.getElementById after that which makes It more preferable to use it in standard serialized way from first without these ! I do not think its serialization take much performance cost in response to scenario I displayed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Blazor` object is a JavaScript object in global namespace (`window`) which added by `blazor.webassembly.js` in Blazor WebAssembly or `blazor.server.js` in Blazor Server. It added at the default template of Blazor Apps at the end of index.html (or _Host.cshtml) by following script:

```
<script autostart="false" src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
```

The `Blazor` object provide `Blazor.platform`  and some useful api for example `start()` for manual start of Blazor.
This script also add another object named `BINDING` to global namespace (`window.BINDING` or simply `BINDING`).
They provide methods for working with .NET objects directly from JavaScript in unmarshalled way. for example you can read different type of data using

```
Blazor.platform.read....
```

You can read objects like `ElementReference` type object using:

```
Blazor.platform.readObjectField(fields,index)
```

Here fields is the input (struct or class) passed to JS function when you invoke it and index is its field offset in struct/class definition. You can read more about field offset in Microsoft documentations [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.fieldoffsetattribute?view=net-6.0).
Here is some example:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct InteropStruct
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public string Name;

        [FieldOffset(8)]
        public int Year;
    }
```

You can also return a .Net object directly from JavaScript functions using `BINDING` as below:

```
return BINDING.js_string_to_mono_string(`Hello, ${name} (${year})!`);
```

You can discover more about these two objects in your browser developer tool for example by writing `Blazor.platform.` or `BINDING.`: